Oracle oml4R model name
How can I assign a model name to an in-database model built using Oracle Machine Learning for R
(OML4R)?
This is what I tried
R> settings = list(RFOR_MTRY = 3)
R> MOD <- ore.odmRF(AFFINITY_CARD~., DF.train, odm.settings= settings)
Also tried reading the documentation.

Include the model name in the model_name parameter and include it to the odm.settings parameter in the model build function:
R> settings = list(RFOR_MTRY = 3, model_name="RF_CLASSIFICATION_MODEL")
R> MOD <- ore.odmRF(AFFINITY_CARD~., DF.train, odm.settings= settings) 
R> MOD$name
'RF_CLASSIFICATION_MODEL'

